# Draw overlapping border with CSS onto varying size images

Tags: html, image, css, border

I am hoping to create a border on my images through CSS as a class tag. Ideally it would look like the example included below where each border line (top, right, bottom, and left) is offset -0.75 rem (or any fixed length) from the edge of the image, overlapping to create a frame inside of the image. It would need to work on images of different sizes and orientations to produce a consistent looking frame across the site. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Is it possible to do through through just CSS?

[Image example of effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FITA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `<img>` tag with a `<div>`, and use the div's `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to draw the borders. The `<div>` element size will fit itself to the image inside because of `display: inline-block`.

```css
.imageFrame {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0; /** required to remove white space **/
}

.imageFrame::before, .imageFrame::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  content: '';
}

.imageFrame::before {
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
}

.imageFrame::after {
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

.smaller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageFrame">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/625769159339737088/2dwpQAXA.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageFrame">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/6f/7a/bb/6f7abbd4d03bf30068cdec219a29a1a9.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageFrame">
  <img class="smaller" src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cat-black-superstitious-fcs-cat-myths-162286659.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this! Would the images maintain the effect if they are bigger and need to be resized for mobile display by css?

Comment: The wrapping div will fit itself to dimensions of the wrapped img tag. Look at the 3rd example I've added (the black cat).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for; I really appreciate your effort! Yes, it works perfectly on responsive/fluid images

Comment: Welcome :) It was an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working example:

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
  height:160px;
  background-image:url('http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg');
  bacground-size:cover;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:10px;
}
.innerOne{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerOne">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The borders don't overlap like the op wanted.